# divided key value from list into two value for dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Want to divided key **'b'** value from  **['2','3']** into **'b1':'2'**,**'b2':'3'** for each set of dictionary

**Original Coding:**

```
x = [{'a': '1','b': ['2', '3'], 'c': '4'},{'a': '5','b': ['6', '7'],'c': '8'},{'a': '9','b': ['10', '11'],'c': '12'}]
```

**print(x)**

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': '4'},
{'a': '5', 'b': ['6', '7'], 'c': '8'},
{'a': '9', 'b': ['10', '11'], 'c': '12'}]
```

**Expected Result**

```
x = [{'a': '1','b1': '2','b2': '3', 'c': '4'},{'a': '5','b1': '6','b2': '7','c': '8'},{'a': '9','b1': '10','b2': '11','c': '12'}]
```

**print(x)**

```
[{'a': '1', 'b1': '2', 'b2': '3', 'c': '4'},
{'a': '5', 'b1': '6', 'b2': '7', 'c': '8'},
{'a': '9', 'b1': '10', 'b2': '11', 'c': '12'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [`update`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp) with `zip`

`[f'b{i}' for i in range(1, len(i['b'])+1)]` will create `b1, b2` so on depending on the length of the list.

```py
x = [{'a': '1','b': ['2', '3'], 'c': '4'},{'a': '5','b': ['6', '7'],'c': '8'},{'a': '9','b': ['10', '11'],'c': '12'}]

for d in x:
    d.update(zip([f'b{i}' for i in range(1, len(d['b'])+1)], d['b']))
    del d['b']

print(x)
```

```
[{'a': '1', 'c': '4', 'b1': '2', 'b2': '3'}, {'a': '5', 'c': '8', 'b1': '2', 'b2': '3'}, {'a': '9', 'c': '12', 'b1': '2', 'b2': '3'}]
```

Comment: it should be `d['b']` not `i['b']`

Comment: also in `range`

Comment: correct, i actually kept the name as i and forgot to change later. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

A home-made solution, base on old list to create new result list, rather than to change old list.

code:

```
x = [{'a': '1','b': ['2', '3'], 'c': '4'},{'a': '5','b': ['6', '7'],'c': '8'},{'a': '9','b': ['10', '11'],'c': '12'}]
result = []
for element in x:
    temp = {}
    for k,v in element.items():
        if k == "b":
            for idx,ele in enumerate(v):
                temp[f"{k}{idx+1}"] = ele
        else:
            temp[k] = v
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

result:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b1': '2', 'b2': '3', 'c': '4'}, 
{'a': '5', 'b1': '6', 'b2': '7', 'c': '8'}, 
{'a': '9', 'b1': '10', 'b2': '11', 'c': '12'}]
```

Comment: Having an explanation would make this better.